# how to access the extra data in the returned intent and update TextView in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am trying to update the value in the First activity. For this. I have passed parameters from first Activity to second with intent and update text input. Now I want to pass the updated value to the first Activity and update the specific value. I try to send data inside saveButton onClick with setResult() method. And get value in FirstActivity with onActivityResult() method. But it does not update the value. Can you please check where I did a mistake?

First Activity

```
class ShowProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var fullnameTv: TextView
    private lateinit var nicknameTv: TextView
    private lateinit var locationTv: TextView
    private lateinit var emailTv: TextView
    private lateinit var bioTv: TextView

    // todo load from sp
    private val mockUser: User? = User("TestName", "test", "test@gmail.com", "Italy", "this is a mocked bio")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_profile)

        fullnameTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_name_tv)
        nicknameTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_nickname_tv)
        locationTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_location_tv)
        emailTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_email_tv)
        bioTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_bio_tv)


        // init views with user data
        fullnameTv.text = mockUser?.fullname
        nicknameTv.text = mockUser?.nickname
        locationTv.text = mockUser?.location
        emailTv.text = mockUser?.email
        bioTv.text = mockUser?.bio




        var editButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.editBtn);
        editButton.setOnClickListener {
            editProfile();
        }
    }

    fun editProfile() {
        val intent = Intent(this@ShowProfileActivity,EditProfileActivity::class.java)
        if (mockUser != null) {
            intent.putExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname", mockUser.fullname)
            intent.putExtra("group23.lab1.user_nickname", mockUser.nickname)
            intent.putExtra("group23.lab1.user_location", mockUser.location)
            intent.putExtra("group23.lab1.user_email", mockUser.email)
            intent.putExtra("group23.lab1.user_bio", mockUser.bio)
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if (data != null) {
                if (mockUser != null) {
                    mockUser.fullname= data.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname").toString() //not updated
                }
            }
        }

    }





    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.show_profile_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_show_profile_edit -> {
                /*
                TODO start edit profile activity (check activity name)
                val intent = Intent(this, com.group23.lab1.EditProfileActivity::class.java).apply {
                    if (mockUser != null) {
                        putExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname", mockUser.fullname)
                        putExtra("group23.lab1.user_nickname", mockUser.nickname)
                        putExtra("group23.lab1.user_location", mockUser.location)
                        putExtra("group23.lab1.user_email", mockUser.email)
                        putExtra("group23.lab1.user_bio", mockUser.bio)
                    }
                }
                startActivityForResult(intent)
                */
                Toast.makeText(this, "OPEN EDIT PROFILE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Second Activity

```
class EditProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var fullnameTv: TextView
    private lateinit var nicknameTv: TextView
    private lateinit var locationTv: TextView
    private lateinit var emailTv: TextView
    private lateinit var bioTv: TextView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile)

        val intent = intent

        fullnameTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_name_tv)
        nicknameTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_nickname_tv)
        locationTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_location_tv)
        emailTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_email_tv)
        bioTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_bio_tv)
//        ageTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_age_tv)

        fullnameTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname")
        nicknameTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_nickname")
        locationTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_location")
        emailTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_email")
        bioTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_bio")



        var sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

        var saveButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSave)

        val name = sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_fullname", null)
        val nickName = sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_nickname", null)
        val location = sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_location", null)
        val email = sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_emai", null)
        val bio = sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_bio", null)

        fullnameTv.text = name
        nicknameTv.text = nickName
        locationTv.text = location
        emailTv.text = email
        bioTv.text = bio

        saveButton.setOnClickListener {

            val name = fullnameTv.text.toString()
            val nickName = nicknameTv.text.toString()
            val location = locationTv.text.toString()
            val email = emailTv.text.toString()
            val bio = bioTv.text.toString()
//            var age = ageTv.text.toString()

            editor.apply {
                putString("group23.lab1.user_fullname", name)
                putString("group23.lab1.user_nickname", nickName)
                putString("group23.lab1.user_location", location)
                putString("group23.lab1.user_email", email)
                putString("group23.lab1.user_bio", bio)
                apply();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();

            }
        }




    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.show_profile_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_show_profile_edit -> {


                Toast.makeText(this, "OPEN EDIT PROFILE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try to remove this line `startActivity(intent)` keep only `startActivityForResult()` in your firstActivity

Comment: yes I deleted, but problem is not related to this

Comment: I don't see where you changed the parameters in the secondActivity one before calling `setResult()`

Comment: I think you sent the same Intent that's why your result has not changed

Comment: I try to change inside saveButton.setOnClickListener. editor.apply. When I change, it is visible in secondActivity

Comment: and when I restart application, my changes keep in secondActivity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230694/discussion-between-shay-kin-and-neo).

Answer (score 0):

You start your activity 2 times:

startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
startActivity(intent)

Comment: yes, I noticed thanks. I removed but still same problem

Comment: You dont change the intent before calling setResult(RESULT_OK, intent), so you just return the same intent that you send in the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your problem is that you're passing back the second activity's original intent, which has the original values that came from the first activity. You need to pass back a new intent with new data.

```
// Return a NEW intent with NEW data, not this Activity's current intent
val resultIntent = Intent().putString("group23.lab1.user_fullname", name) 
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

---

Beyond that, here's a few unsolicited suggestions:

1 - Remove redundant startForActivity:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
startActivity(intent) // <- Delete this
```

2 - Check for the same intent code in onActivityResult. This ensures you're handling the correct result. Doesn't matter in your case as you only have one result, but it's good to build that habit and be correct. So since you started with requestCode 1, check for that same value in the result:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) { // Check for same request code
            if (data != null) {
                if (mockUser != null) {
                    mockUser.fullname= data.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname").toString() //not updated
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

3 - Saving a local val named "intent" to shadow the activity's own "intent" property is redundant.

```
val intent = intent // Delete this - it's pointless
```

4 - You are setting values in the second activity twice - from the intent and then overwriting that with shared preferences. Pick one.

```
// Setting values here from Intent ...
fullnameTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname")
nicknameTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_nickname")
locationTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_location")
emailTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_email")
bioTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_bio")

var sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
var editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

var saveButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSave)

val name = sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_fullname", null)
val nickName = sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_nickname", null)
val location = sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_location", null)
val email = sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_emai", null)
val bio = sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_bio", null)

// ... get completely overwritten here ... so setting them above is pointless
fullnameTv.text = name
nicknameTv.text = nickName
locationTv.text = location
emailTv.text = email
bioTv.text = bio
```

5 - Related to the above, you seem to be mixing and matching intents and shared preferences. Unless you actually need this data to persist to disk as "preferences", you should remove the shared preferences logic which is confusing things. On the other hand, if you do need to persist the data, then you can remove the passing of data via intents, as it ends up being redundant.

For example, your activity result could read from the shared preferences instead:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) { // Check for same request code
            if (mockUser != null) {
                var sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                mockUser.fullname= sharedPreferences.getString("group23.lab1.user_fullname", "")
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note that if you chose to use preferences, you should use `Editor.commit()` which is synchronous instead of `Editor.apply()` which is asynchronous, to ensure you values are ready to be read immediately by the next activity.